# Realm Proper way of Copy Object In Transaction with RxJava

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

Currently, when copying a value to realm, i do the following:

```
public void addToRealm(Home item, RealmChangeListener<E> listener) {

    realm.executeTransaction((Realm realm1) ->
            realm1.copyToRealm(item).addChangeListener<Home>(listener));
}
```

And then i can access the newly added object inside the listener. What is the proper RxJava way of accomplishing the same? The observable must return
`Observable<Home>`, which is the realmCopy not the original object. Can any1 please provide a sample?

Managed to get it working by doing this, altought im not sure it is the best approach... What is the recommended approach?

```
return Observable.just(homeItem)
                        .map { (HomeItem homeItem) ->
                            return AnotherHomeItem(homeItem.xxx, homeItem.yyy)
                        }
                        .flatMap { (AnotherHomeItem anotherItem) -> 
                            realm.beginTransaction()
                            val newItem = realm.copyToRealm(anotherItem).asObservable< AnotherHomeItem >()
                            realm.commitTransaction()
                            return newItem
                        }
                        .filter {
                            return it.isLoaded
                        }
```

Comment: no sorry, It is but i wanted to present it as Java code. Just forgot method prefix. thanks

Comment: ya its fine thanks. I was assuming retrolambda has the same syntax as kotlin lambdas, but they are slightly different you right :p thanks

Comment: its fine. don't waste time with that :p you already helped me, android ppl is used to retrolambda

Comment: What's in the listener? And if your listener is being called... then what thread are you doing `executeTransaction()` on?

Comment: the listener just gets the data and fill some views with it. need to use the managed object and not the one passed in. same thread, otherwise this can't be done.

Comment: I need to ask, do you use `findAll()` or `findAllAsync()`?

Comment: you are missing the point. Read the edited answer

Comment: II'm writing not reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write to the Realm on a background thread, and observe with a different subscription on the UI thread.

You persist with one subscription on the background thread:

```
public Subscription downloadObjectsFromNetwork() {
    return objectApi.getObjects()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(response -> {
            try(Realm realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                realmInstance.executeTransaction(realm -> realm.insertOrUpdate(response.objects));
            }
        });
}
```

And you read with `asObservable()` on the UI thread:

```
public Subscription readFromRealm() {
    return realm.where(SomeObject.class)
         .findAllAsync()
         .asObservable()
         .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
         .subscribe(objects -> adapter.updateData(objects));
}
```

---

**Using Realm with RxJava**

For queries, Realm provides the `realmResults.asObservable()` method. Observing results is only possible on looper threads (typically the UI thread).

For this to work, your configuration must contain the following

```
realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)       //
                          .rxFactory(new RealmObservableFactory()) //
                             //...
                          .build();
```

Afterwards, you can use your results as an observable.

```
Observable<RealmResults<SomeObject>> observable = results.asObservable();
```

For asynchronous queries, you should filter the results by `isLoaded()`, so that you receive an event only when the query has been executed. This `filter()` is not needed for synchronous queries (`isLoaded()` always returns `true` on sync queries).

```
    Subscription subscription = RxTextView.textChanges(editText).switchMap(charSequence -> 
        realm.where(SomeObject.class)
             .contains("searchField", charSequence.toString(), Case.INSENSITIVE)
             .findAllAsync()
             .asObservable())
    .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded) //
    .subscribe(objects -> adapter.updateData(objects));
```

For writes, you should either use the `executeTransactionAsync()` method, or open a Realm instance on the background thread, execute the transaction synchronously, then close the Realm instance.

```
public Subscription loadObjectsFromNetwork() {
    return objectApi.getObjects()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(response -> {
            try(Realm realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                realmInstance.executeTransaction(realm -> realm.insertOrUpdate(response.objects));
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info. One other thing, are queries that fast on Realm that makes it viable to query in the main thread. Or is it encouraged to do so because it currently don't support switching threads? One thing that bugs me the most is that RealmResults can't be passed between threads, and i think it should be on Realm's top priority list. Unless queries are extremelly fast and so it has low priorities.

Comment: It's not really true that there is NO way to offload the query to another thread. It's just not simple (thread handoff), so Realm handles it for you when you're using the `findAllAsync()` method.  As long as you use @Index on the fields you use in your query, it should be pretty fast though. Async query methods require you to be on the (looper) main thread though, because the results are delivered through the handler. So while you can't just jump between threads, Realm has async query methods to offload the evaluation of the results to a different thread.